# cakephp jquery onclick alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp-2.4

I have a form with select input. I want to show an alert when the dropdown list was selected.
view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Office');
echo $this->Form->input('under_office', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $settings,'empty'   => false));
echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>
```

controller

```
public function add() {


    $settings = $this->Office->Officetype->find('list', array('fields'=> array('Officetype.id', 'Officetype.name')
    ));
      $this->set(compact('settings'));

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Office->create();
            $post_data = $this->request->data;
            if ($this->Office->save($post_data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Office details saved successfully'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to save Office details'));
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This may helps to you, first put some id on your select tag.

```
echo $this->Form->input('under_office', array('type' => 'select', 'id' => 'myselect', 'options' => $settings,'empty'  => false));
```

After that where those above code is executed, place below code between `<script> </script>` tag or at where your javascript is exist,

```
document.getElementById('myselect').onchange = function (){
    alert('hello guys');
}
```